# ElasticSearch Sort on Multi-Value Not Working

Tags: sorting, search, elasticsearch

Pretty simple issue here - I have a instance where I am searching for a wildcard value using "query_string", but the sort order is not working. Here is my query:

```
query": {
  "query_string": {
     "query": "60* Min*",
     "fields": [
        "beer_name",
        "beer_index",
        "spelling_alt",
        "brewery_alias",
        "alias_alt"
     ]
  }
 },
 "sort": [
   { "popularity" : {"order" : "desc"} }
 ]
```

This should return the values in descending order (popularity is an "interger"), from heighest to lowest, but this doesn't sort anything, it's done by random order it appears. Any gudiance  here?

Comment: Not really sure about the question, what do you mean with multi-value? Is the popularity a multi-value field?

Comment: did you run an explain query? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was the _mapping popularity was set to string. I simply updated the _mapping to a LONG or INT and the problem was solved.